# the first principal component’s variance

Tags: statistics, variance, svd, principal-component-analysis

The expression comes from **The Elements of Statistical Learning**p66(3.49)

Related part about this is shown in below figure.
[image]

Where Using SVD, $X$ has the form: $X=UDV^T$. And $D$ is a diagonal matrix, with diagonal entries $d_1\geq d_2\geq…\geq d_p\geq0$

I don’t know why the variance has a $1/N$. How to conduct it?

I have look up for some material about PCA, but I don’t find the answer…Maybe a silly problem, but I still need your helpThank you!